# WPF MVVM and parent-child combobox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, combobox

I'm sure I already found this on StackOverflow, but I don't seem to be smart enough to find it again

What I want to do (in WPF using MVVM) is this:

```
cmbSelectedAddressRegion: populated with the list of region
cmbSelectedAddressCities: populated with the list of cities in that region
```

When the user click on a region in `cmbSelectedAddressRegion` the items in `cmbSelectedAddressCities` should be the cities of that region only

I have an XAML like this

```
    <ComboBox Name="cmbSelectedAddressRegion" 
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=selectedAddressItemRegion, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=selectedAddressIsEnabled}" 
Style="{StaticResource style_flat_ComboBox}"></ComboBox>

    <ComboBox Name="cmbSelectedAddressCities" 
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=selectedAddressIdCities, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="id" 
SelectedValuePath="id" 
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cmbSelectedAddressRegion, Path=SelectedItem.Cities}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=selectedAddressIsEnabled}" 
Style="{StaticResource style_flat_ComboBox}"></ComboBox>
```

When I click on a region in cmbSelectedAddressRegion the cmbSelectedAddressCities is correctly populated

I also have a VM `vmCustomer` with a lot of `DependencyProperties` (amongst them `selectedAddressItemRegion` and `selectedAddressIdCities`)
When I select the customer from the master list (another combobox in the window which holds the list of customers) I see the `cmbSelectedAddressRegion` correctly showing the Region, but I don't see anything in the `cmbSelectedAddressCities`. Again if I click on the `cmbSelectedAddressRegion` the `cmbSelectedAddressCities` is populated and the currently selected cities (in the `vmCustomer`) is selected

The `cmbSelectedAddressRegion.itemssource` is bounded (in bode behind file) to an `ObservableCollection(of vmAddressRegion)`
Each `vmAddressRegion` has, amongst other DependencyProperties, a `cities` properties which returns an `ObservableCollection(of vmAddressCities)`

The `ObservableCollection(of vmAddressRegion)` is populated when the window is created. At the same time, for every item of `ObservableCollection(of vmAddressRegion)` (of type `vmAddressRegion`) the `ObservableCollection(of vmAddressCities)` is populated with the corresponding items)

I hope I've been clear enough
Any suggestion how to resolve the problem above (the `cmbSelectedAddressCities` not being "populated")?

Thanks for any help

Comment: your ViewModels should not have DependencyProperties.

Comment: why? maybe I got it all wrong? I started using MVVM reading from here [link](http://community.visual-basic.it/alessandro/archive/2010/06/15/29563.aspx).

Comment: Your link is in italian language, so I couldn't understand a lot of it (it is also in VB which at this point hurts my eyes just to look at it), but from what I see, he's doing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the ViewModels, which removes the need for DependencyProperties

Comment: And to answer your question Why? its because DependencyProperties are a WPF concept, and your ViewModels should be view-agnostic (that is, not dependant on any UI technology)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the link was in italian
OK got it, then the problem it's my description. I too used the INotifyPropertyChanged in my ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

The WPF ComboBox needs to be handled with care. Bindings easily get confused if ItemsSource and SelectedValue/SelectedItem change in the "wrong" order, especially if you use SelectedValue.

My advice would be to replace the "SelectedValue" bindings with "SelectedItem". The binding expressions can stay the same (although I don't think you need to specify the UpdateSourceTrigger).

Binding to SelectedItem means that your **vmCustomer** needs a **selectedAddressCity** property instead of the selectedAddressIdCity id (and you can remove cmbSelectedAddressCities' SelectedValuePath).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sphinxxx. I already did the same exact thing (even the name of the property: selectedAddressCity). After digging a bit more, I found out the real problem. It's a little complicated to explain and I don't have enough time right now (I'm in office). I will post the details and the solution later this week (in case someone happens to have the same problem).

Comment: That's good to hear, and I'm looking forward to seeing your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the long delay.

I know I promised to post back my solution during the end of the week, but my pc decided to die the following day.
Regarding my original problem I adopted 2 "solutions".
First I removed the numeric ID changing it to the full description of the Region/City. I thought this was good, but the problem still remained for some "strange" cases (for example when clicking the first time on the Region combobox.
After digging a while in the code I discovered the real problem was in a converter I wrote for the application. During a conversion I made a mistake: instead of "**if isnothing**" I wrote "**if not isnothing**" and the resulting was a nothing converted to space, messing up the whole father-child relation.
As I was worried, the problem was in my code, and not in the piece of code I posted here.

I thanks again everyone, and apologize again for the delay